# Is not a valid Win32 application on a 64-bit machine

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, itunes, 32-bit, file-corruption

I get this error:

> iTunes64Setup.exe is not a valid Win32 application

But I do have a 64-bit machine and operating system ([Intel Core I3](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_Core#Core_i3) and Windows 7).

What can be the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens a lot when the download is corrupted. Delete the installer, clear your temp files and try to download it again.

Comment: It's worth noting that it **IS NOT** saying 32-bit can't be run on 64-bit